# Why do I see external CSS overriding embedded CSS?

Tags: css

According to [this source](http://www.boogiejack.com/CSS_4.html), when there are conflicting CSS styles on the same element, embedded styles override external styles but that is not what I have observed.

I have the following HTML (simplified):

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.min.css" />
  <style type="text/css">
  .dialog_error_container
  {
    display: none;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dialog_error_container alert-box alert">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to see the rule defined for `.dialog_error_container` taking precedence over the one for `div.alert-box` but I got the opposite result (see the image below)

[image]

Please explain to me why the embedded style doesn't override the external style.

Comment: I think it is because embedded css is not specific enough. You might  wanna try.

`.dialog_error_container.alert-box.alert {
display: none;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source cited is in error. Check out the authoritative specification: CSS 2.1, clause 6.4.1 [Cascading order](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order). With respect to “origin”, both external and embedded style sheets are “author style sheets”. Thus, the next criterion is specificity, and `.dialog_error_container` (just a class selector) is less specific than `div.alert-box` (element type selector combined with class selector).

Using `div.dialog_error_container` instead would make the specificity equal. *Then* “sort by order” would step in, and the embedded style sheet would win – not by virtue of being embedded but due to being later (the `style` element in this case appears after the `link` element that refers to the external style sheet).

Thus, it would be safer (against future reorganizations of the style sheets) to make the specificity higher, e.g. by using `body div.dialog_error_container` (a bit artificial, but it works, and it’s better than using `!important`, which should be last resort only).

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between external and embedded CSS—they’re both treated exactly the same. The reason it doesn’t override is because `div.alert-box` is more specific than `.dialog_error_container`.  Breaking down the specificity:

- `div.alert-box` gets a specificity of 0,0,1,1 because it has 1 class and 1 element.
- `.dialog_error_container` gets a specificity of 0,0,1,0 because it has 1 class.

If the specificity of these two were the same then whichever one is defined last wins.

Note that it is generally best to make your CSS selectors have the lowest specificity possible, as this makes them easier to override.

Comment: In calculating specificity, class and element selectors are not added. Here the specificities are 0,0,1,1 and 0,0,1,0. Check from the specs, or use the calculator http://css-specificity.webapp-prototypes.appspot.com/

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That’s what I get for answering while tired—thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That link is leading you astray. Embedded and external styles have the same level of specificity, it then comes down to the selector. In which case `div.alert-box` is more specific than `.dialog_error_container`

The easiest way to create the behaviour you're after with what you have is to change the embedded selector to `div.dialog_error_container`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the external css overrides the embedded style because it is more specific; it has rules for `div.alert-box`, both an element and a class while the embedded style has `.dialog_error_container`, a class.